# Apollo gql, get loading state when polling

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am using @apollo/client v3. I want to get loading state when requests will happen from polling but it is not working as I expect.

This is my query

```
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(SOME_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      variable: "value",
    },
    10000  //poll interval
  });
```

I wrote useEffect to catch if it is loading or not when polling

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loading)
  }, [loading]);
```

This is runs only for first request but in browsers network tab I see that requests is happening every 10seconds (10000 milliseconds, because of polling). How can I catch state when loading is happening or polling is started for all requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` to true will solve it.

```js
const { data, loading } = useQuery(SOME_QUERY, {
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  pollInterval: 10000,
  variables: {
    variable: "value",
  },
});

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(loading)
}, [loading]);
```